# I am trying to specify a font in a created PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fonts

I am using [niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) to create a PDF file in Laravel. I'd like to use the Arial font however the font is not working.

```php
$pdf = PDF::loadView('blade', $data, [], [
    'format' => 'A4-L',
    'orientation' => 'L'
]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was stuck in same issue. Below is its exact solution

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('blade',$data, [], [
                     format' => 'A4-L',
                     'orientation' => 'L',
                     'mode' => 'c'
                    ]);
```

and in blade file you should need to add on top

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It working fine for me. Bypassing mode c it works. Save my time. Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, mode => c was trick. it overrides default fonts...You can use any other fonts in CSS files now. I spent lot of time on my time to fix this. I almost read whole the package then I was able to fix this

Comment: Thanks a ton!! I wish I could give 100000... up votes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to use a specific font.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```